# Bayes' Theorem and Complement of Both Events

Tags: probability, statistics, bayes-theorem

Does it make sense to use the complement of both events when finding a probability using Bayes' Theorem?

For ex: say that 60% of 911 calls concern domestic disputes, and only 3% of those domestic abuse calls end with an arrest being made. Furthermore suppose that 92% of all police calls don't end in an arrest.

What is the probability that a police call that *does not* concern a domestic dispute *does not* result in an arrest.

My attempt at this would be to find P(A'|D'): the probability there's no arrest given that it's not a domestic dispute.
 I did that and got 0.368, but I'm not sure if that number makes sense given the scenario.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That kind of question can be answered without using Bayes Rule:
A call to 911 can lead be related to domestic violence or not, there is no other posibilities. Also, they are disjoint so they form a partition. Then:
$$
P(A^{C}) = P(A^{C} \cap D) + P(A^{C} \cap D^{C}) = P(A^{C} | D) P(D) + P(A^{C} | D^{C}) P(D^{C})
$$
And now solving for $P(A^{C} | D^{C})$
$$
P(A^{C} | D^{C}) = \frac{P(A^{C}) -  P(A^{C} | D) P(D)}{P(D^{C})}
$$

However, regarding your original question, yes, you can apply Bayes rule to any complement of sets, furthermore, you could apply to any union and intersections of sets too. For example:
$$
P(A^{C} | D^{C}) = \frac{P(D^{C} | A^{C}) P(A^{C})}{P(D^{C})}
$$
Which using the complement turns out to be the expression above. But also for an intersection for example:
$$
P(A \cap B | C) = \frac{P(C | A \cap B) P(A \cap B)}{P(C)}
$$